# How to change the commas to space?

Tags: discord.js

So I created a poll command, but when I type in the command, there are commas between each word.

```
exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  let text = message.content.slice('__poll'.length);
  if (!args) return message.reply("You must have something to vote for!")
    message.channel.send(`:ballot_box:  ${message.author.username} started a poll! React to my next message to vote on it. :ballot_box: `);
    const pollTopic = await message.channel.send(`${args}`);
    pollTopic.react(`✅`);
    pollTopic.react(`⛔`);
};
```

when I want the question to be What is up, this happens

`what,is,up!`

Comment: `args` is an array, so it prints with commas in between each array entry. If you use `args.join(' ')` it'll concatenate all the strings and separate them with the specified separator (in this case a space: ' ')

Answer (score 1):

By default, when translating an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) into a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), JavaScript will separate each element by a comma. To change the delimiter, you can use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Example:

```js
const arr = ['How', 'are', 'you?'];
console.log(`Original: ${arr}`);

const str = arr.join(' ');
console.log(`Joined: ${str}`);
```